# Limit Graphql results that belongs to owner in Strapi

Tags: graphql, strapi

I am using a simple Strapi policy like below to limit the REST result that belongs to the owner only, which documented in the following link.

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/624

```
module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  const { id, role } = ctx.state.user;
  if(role !== 'administrator'){
    ctx.query.owner = id;
  }
  await next();
};
```

Now I want to do the same for Graphql results, but it doesn't seems to work with the same code because "ctx.query" is undefined. I have tried looking at the all the request API but none of them seems to be work for Graphql query. The URL ended like 'http://localhost:1337/graphql', and 'ctx.request.query' is an empty [].

https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/requests.html#api-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here what I did to solve that problem:

Override the GraphQl Schema in `api/activity/config/schema.graphql`

```
module.exports = {
    definition: ``,
    query: `
        notifications(sort: String, limit: Int, start: Int, where: JSON): [Activity]
    `,
    type: {},
    resolver: {
        Query: {
            notifications: {
                description: 'Return the auth user notifications',
                policies: ['plugins.users-permissions.permissions'],
                resolver: 'Activity.findNotifications'
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Create a new function resolver in `api/activity/controllers/Activity.js`

```
module.exports = {

    findNotifications(ctx) {

        ctx.query = { ...ctx.query, owner: ctx.state.user.id }

        if (ctx.query._q) {
            return strapi.services.activity.search(ctx.query);
        }
        return strapi.services.activity.find(ctx.query);
    },
}
```

In the controller you got the query and add the owner id filter.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking at REST docs while searching for graphQL problem? There is no url query parsing at all.

Owner role (permissions) can be checked using policies - it's described [here](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/graphql.html#execute-a-policy-before-a-resolver).

The following sections contain examples of misc permission/customization - resolvers have a `context` parameter. User data should (did't checked) be available at `context.state.user`.

Comment: context.state.user has the information of my user, but I need to change the search query of graphql so that the result returned would be filtered. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The isOwner policy from the link updated the query of REST before firing it, but the same cannot be applied on graphQL.

Comment: you can use a custom resolver (next example) - modify 'where' used in mutation part (query part is hardcoded) of example or filter results before returning

Comment: I was looking at the the example in https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/graphql.html#customise-the-graphql-schema section "Apply permissions on a query". Seems like I can change the options within "resolver: (obj, options, context) => {}" to modify the query, but am stuck with error "Your filters contain a field 'where' that doesn't appear on your model definition nor it's relations".

Comment: you need to have an `owner` field in model you want to be filtered by owner - then you can use `where: { owner: context.state.user... }`

Comment: The problem seems to be from Strapi. 1) If I used policy, I could not modify the query of GraphQL as it does not works the same way like REST. 2) If I try to change the resolver via `resolverOf` in Strapi, policies are not loaded so I could not get the owner ID via `ctx.state.user`.

Comment: hmmm, "There is no custom resolver in that case" - very strange limitation - open an issue on github - probably you need to load user/permission plugin in custom resolver

Comment: Yup, raised one. https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3413 Thanks for the help.